# Why do we waste so much Screen-Real-Estate?

Tags: mobile, design, responsive-design, screen-real-estate

**Border around the screen**

*this basically boils down to why dont make the whole front of device a screen and why have borders around everything on the screen too.*

**Why not replace the material around screens with the screens?**

I guess the reason (a very bad one) to have a border around a screen might be to make device thinner (components inside are more spread out) but I certainly (and probably most people) prefer bigger screen and a bit thicker device than the same bit thinner and wasted space.

*Why also have borders inside screens*
In my opinion one border is very stupid.But *another border inside the screen* and *on outside* is completely idiotic.

**This issue is most apparent on small devices like smartphones.**

Not the best example: Galaxy S2 (right click to view in new tab to view at full 2000x2217 resolution)
[image: right click to view in new tab to view at full 2000x2217 resolution]

Comment: So what exactly is the question here? Seems like you asked the question in title and then answer it in your post.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Im asking the question and explaining how I view this issue.

Comment: Then what you should do is edit your question so that it's a clear question and that it's _just_ a question. Then simply add an answer alongside everyone else. There's nothing wrong with that!

Comment: @CodeMaverick hahaha very funny.You just put the question on hold."As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking" Are you unable to see the question??? (Id edit my question so my own viewpoint would be in answer instead of the post with the question but you closed it and it seems its because you are unable to see what Im asking)

Comment: 1) It takes 5 close votes to close a question. 2) It's unclear because the only question that seems to be asked is in the title.  In the post itself, all it seemed you were doing was answering the question in the title.  That's not how you ask a question. 3) I didn't downvote you in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 6):

We always need a negative space around our content and that negative space helps our mind comprehend which sections of content are connected and which are separated.

[image]

There is another concern and that is related to perception of content. if there was no border around the  content, how would you know if the words which are now touching the edge of the screen are the last words of sentence or there are more words after that? Visually you wouldn't know and you would need to try to scroll and find if it scrolls or not. If you have a border bounding your content, you can tell that visually.

Comment: I disagree because the "perception of content" will be better because there will be less distractions and the content can be made to fit the screen (like text on mobile devices (but it is still resized with a border)) so you will visually know because the sentence or whatever make sense.(so scroll bars will be a thing of the past)

Answer (score 1):

> Why not replace the material around screens with the screens?

Do you have a smartphone? If so, you probably use it with **one hand** only.

### **It would be hard to interact *when* you want**

Can you imagine having to interact with an on-screen element that's on the side of the screen next to your palm? You would have to **bend your thumb** in a very uncomfortable way.

### **It would interact when you *don't* want**

I currently own a Nexus 4.

[image]

The border you're talking is **thinner** than on the iPhone. I very often have issues with my palm triggering unwanting taps on the screen.

What would happen if this border was completely absent? I can imagine the *"phantom taps"* would be constant, and also for multi-touch interactions.

Overall, this small border is there for **comfort**. That's why it will probably be there for a very long time.

On a side note, a smaller phone would be harder to handle. And a bigger screen as well. That's why [the iPhone stays the same over the years](http://dcurt.is/3-point-5-inches):

[image]

Comment: I own a smartphone and this is certainly not true "You would have to bend your thumb in a very uncomfortable way."Just try to touch the edge of the device while holding it with one hand. Unless you have some finger rheumatism or some other condition this should pose no problem to you

Answer (score 0):

Part of the answer to this has to do with the manufacturing process. Components are still undergoing lots of refinement and currently need that space to mount the screen on.

I can't recall where I read this but I know the LG team made their G2 phone with buttons on the back so the parts wouldn't interfere with screen-size so in essence it's more edge to edge than other smartphones.

Comment: I've completely disassembled and reassembled my smartphone several times and seen other smartphones disassembled and it always seems the screen can be made larger without making device larger.Also at least on the S2 the buttons are in the plastic body **below the screen** so they don't interfere with screen size either.

Answer (score 0):

One reason may be cost:  it's probably more expensive to manufacture a screen with thin borders. The border has to hide the electronic connectors to the display screen and the touch detection electronics. Advances in manufacturing may now mean this is less of a problem than it once was.

Another is durability: if the case is too thin and rigid near the edge, shocks to the corners or sides of the phone will be transferred to the display screen. The face of a sheet of Gorilla Glass may be very strong, but the glass display screen is extremely thin and fragile, and the edges are even less so, yet it's the edges that are exposed to the most accidental abuse. So the border has to contain and hide the mechanical mounting, which needs to include a layer of shock absorbing space.

Finally, there needs to be room for adhesives, sealing the outer glass to the case. The case needs to be fully sealed, or dirt will enter and get behind the glass, ruining the phone.

Comment: The glass/screen can be glued on the bottom of it? Anyway if not the sealing doesn't have to rely on glue anyway.I agree with the potentially worse durability but it seems the bezel can be replaced with more of screen anyway.

Comment: The "shock absorbing space" isn't needed in devices like TVs though.How do you explain this?

Comment: Yes, the shock absorbing gap is needed on TVs, as they are handled roughly during installation, and even in use.  Plus, the mounting hardware needs to be stronger for the much more massive screen, and that means thicker.

Comment: They can be handled normally? The wallmounting screws don't have to use a border around the screen because they can be behind the screen? So does your point still stand?